# How to open URI in the native browser (android)

Tags: java, android

I want to open the page ya.ru in the native browser. That's what I have

```
list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "http://ya.ru"; 
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent1.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
});
```

Could you tell me what I should write in `uses-permissions` except

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

or is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Your code looks good. The permission should not even be needed. Did you check that the `onClick()` method gets called when you click on whatever you attached the `OnClickListener()` to?

Comment: Your variable called `list` so I suppose it's a `ListView`. You should probably use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

Comment: could you tell how to get the index of item?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru"));
startActivity(intent);
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml you have to write:

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: You don't need `INTERNET` permission here.

Comment: As Jan mentioned above, try to put Log.i("Log_tag","I am clicked"); inside onClick to check that your view is registering clicks.

Comment: The app don't want to open, it closes immediatly

Comment: thnx, but it works now, there was a silly mistake, as i had ListView